# placeholder attribute in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How could insert the value of a field's db in the plcaholder in zf2

```
<div class="form_element">
<?php
    $this->placeholder('name')->data = $this->data;  
    $name = $form->get('name');
    echo $formLabel->openTag().$name->getOption('label')." ";   
        echo $this->formInput($name);
        echo $formLabel->closeTag();
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify whether you want values prefilled in the form (e.g. for an edit form), or whether you specifically want values using the HTML5 placeholder attribute?

Comment: no , i use zf2 nomenclature , i need get the db values and introduce inthe placeholder (example name:Patrick Nerder...) and later change or keep the value

Answer (score 1):

A [**placeholder is a ViewHelper**](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/view.placeholders.basics.html?highlight=placeholders) and therefore is is designed to help render view content.

In order to use your database data witin a placeholder you will need to ensure that the data is first passed to the *view* from the controller action.

```
public function modificaAlumnoAction()
{
  //...
  return ViewModel('data' => $data); // data passed to the view instance 
}
```

Then within the view script

```
// modifica-alumno.phtml
$this->placeholder('foo')->data = $this->data;
```

An finally output the data (such as within the layout)

```
// layout.phtml
echo $this->placeholder('foo)->data;
```